# Creating and exporting .dat file as desired

Tags: list-manipulation, output-formatting, dataset

Please help me create a .dat file with the data format is
as in the link given below
`https://pastebin.com/CXq0N3aT`
And export the file.
Part of the data format in the above link as follows

```
bag -585,10 ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   88e-6,-88e-6,2e-6   UID_GH-585bsTC
exci    4   -88e-6,88e-6,50e-6  UID_GH-585bsTCdown
bag -580,10 ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   88e-6,-88e-6,2e-6   UID_GH-580bsTC
exci    4   -88e-6,88e-6,50e-6  UID_GH-580bsTCdown
bag -575,10 ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   88e-6,-88e-6,2e-6   UID_GH-575bsTC
exci    4   -88e-6,88e-6,50e-6  UID_GH-575bsTCdown
bag -570,10 ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   88e-6,-88e-6,2e-6   UID_GH-570bsTC
exci    4   -88e-6,88e-6,50e-6  UID_GH-570bsTCdown
bag -565,10 ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   88e-6,-88e-6,2e-6   UID_GH-565bsTC
exci    4   -88e-6,88e-6,50e-6  UID_GH-565bsTCdown
```

All the numbers can be variables. exci, UID, and TC are also variables. I tried using the **Table** but it did not help to produce the same .dat file in the link. Please see below for my efforts.

```
\[CapitalDelta]B = 10;
Ic = N[88 10^-6];
\[CapitalDelta]Ic = N[2 10^-6];
\[CapitalDelta]Icb = N[50 10^-6];
TC = 300;
IS = exci;
ISads = 4;
SampID = UID;
tw = 60;

mylist = TableForm[
  Flatten[Table[{{"bag", {{B, \[CapitalDelta]B}}, "ff"}, {"stay", 
      tw}, {IS, 
      ISads, {{Ic, -Ic, \[CapitalDelta]Ic}}, {StringJoin[{TextString[
          SampID], "_GH", TextString[B], "bs" , 
         TextString[TC]}]}}, {IS, 
      ISads, {{Ic, -Ic, \[CapitalDelta]Icb}}, {StringJoin[{TextString[
          SampID], "_GH", TextString[B], "bs" , TextString[TC], 
         "down"}]}}}, {B, -585, -565, 5}], 1]]
Export["mylist.dat", StringRiffle[mylist, "\n"], "Table"]
```

Output

```
bag -585    10  ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   2.*10^-6    UID_GH-585bs300
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   0.00005 UID_GH-585bs300down
bag -580    10  ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   2.*10^-6    UID_GH-580bs300
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   0.00005 UID_GH-580bs300down
bag -575    10  ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   2.*10^-6    UID_GH-575bs300
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   0.00005 UID_GH-575bs300down
bag -570    10  ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   2.*10^-6    UID_GH-570bs300
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   0.00005 UID_GH-570bs300down
bag -565    10  ff  
stay    60      
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   2.*10^-6    UID_GH-565bs300
exci    4   0.000088    -0.000088   0.00005 UID_GH-565bs300down
```

This is somewhat matches with the data format but still there are few
issues:

1. There is no comma between -585 and 10
2. 0.000088 has to be 88e-6, similarly other numbers

Hope this clarifies. Please feel free to ask if something is not clear.

Comment: Waiting for an answer. Is this not a good question ? experts- please try to help me . Thanks

Comment: Make the question self-contained. Many people don't like to click external links without a good reason. Moreover, the platform itself might not work in many countries due to local restrictions. Provide dat file format with your post or provide a 1-click accessible link to the file.

Comment: @Syed , Thanks much. now edited question. Included data file format. Please let me know if I miss anything

Comment: It is still unclear where you are deriving each of the four entries in every sublist from. Are these randomly generated? What is your question exactly?

Comment: @Syed sorry that it is not so clear. TableForm of the list gives me exactly how the data look like. Please sweep value -585 to -565 in steps of 5 to generate the data while replacing all other entries with some values. I would like to have the format of the data as it is . Thanks

Comment: @Syed, Now I have completely edited my question to make it clear. Hope this helps. Let me know if you need anything more. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Export` is not your friend here, because `Export` is for known data formats, like CSV and JPEG. Your data format is completely custom.

The group of functions you want to use here are `OpenWrite`, `Write`, `WriteString`, and `Close`.

You start by opening a stream:

```
stream = OpenWrite["out.dat"];
```

Then you would write some utility functions, one for each type of data line.

For the bag line it could be:

```
writeBagLine[n_Integer, m_Integer] := WriteString["bag " <> ToString[n] <> "," <> ToString[m] <> " ff"]
```

Or you can use `StringTemplate` if you prefer:

```
writeBagLine[n_Integer, m_Integer] := WriteString[stream, StringTemplate["bag `n`,`m` ff"][<|"n" -> n, "m" -> m|>]]
```

Repeat this for the other lines (they are similar).

For the 0.00088 number formatting use `NumberForm`:

```
ToString[NumberForm[0.0000088, NumberFormat -> (Row[{#1, "e", #3}] &)]]
```

This gives "8.8e-6", if it needs to be more like "88e-6" (with a nonstandard mantissa, let me know)

When you're done writing to your file, you can close the stream:

```
Close[stream]
```

This prevents you from accidentally writing more content to the file.

Comment: @ Arnoud Buzing , thanks for your time. It helped me a lot.

Comment: Good to hear @mrt31 , feel free to my my answer an upvote!